# Reverse ranking order numbers , without an array

Tags: php, algorithm

Let's say we have a ranking system with integers 1 till a maximum of 100.000 .

I want a function that reverses the rank of an integer.

So that value 100.000 becomes rank 1  and  value 1  becomes rank 100.000 .

```
function reverseRank($currentRank,$maxRank){

         // create array with numbers 1 till $maxRank.
         // reverse order of values and return key of $currentRank...
         // but this seems a bit a waste of resources.

         return $reversedRank;
}
```

What would be the best way to do this performance wise in php ?

Comment: Show the table structure for ranking and show what you have tried so far .

Comment: If you don't have an array, where are the integers initially stored? Can there be duplicates?

Comment: So what is reverse of 20.000?

Comment: Alright , the initial idea was to boost some of the search rankings.   Let's say it is a movie database.  We got our own popularity of a title.  but we can use external sources that have their own ranking.  Some use 1 = best rank , some use ( for example) 100.000 best rank.  I don't mind double ranking , it is just a bit extra to order search results.   I want to normalize the ranking.  I will receive a number : for example  1.. I want to put that in our table as 100.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume for simplicity that you have a range of ranks between 1 and 10.

We need to find a mapping function that will swap

```
1  -> 10
2  -> 9
3  -> 8
4  -> 7
5  -> 6
6  -> 5
7  -> 4
8  -> 3
9  -> 2
10 -> 1
```

Now it might be easier to think about the solution.

What function will work for it? This function will have a couple of things known in the runtime. 
Lower and upper bands of the range, so 1 and 10 respectively.

We can sketch this in slightly more formal way:

```
f(1) -> 10
f(2) -> 9 
f(3) -> 8
(...)
f(x) -> y; // 1 and 10 are know to be the limits
```

what if we try to apply

Lets try playing with it. f(1) to be 10 could be:

```
def f(x):
    return x*UPPER_LIMIT
```

Definitely it will break as soon as we try it with `2`.

F(2) -> 9, looking at this I am able to observe that I can write it as:

Lets return a number that is as much smaller from UPPER limit as the x is more than LOWER limit.

```
def f(x):
    return UPPER_LIMIT - (x-LOWER_LIMIT)
```

And, by running it for more values it looks like it works.

I hope I understood your question and that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, simple math ...  Time for me to brush up on my math.  Ten years ago this would have been so obvious to me. Thank you for the extended explanation. +1

Comment: I like that sentence and will remember it.  Thanks mate